# Run Windows Command Line automatically daily

Tags: windows, command-line

How I can make Windows to automatically run this command from Windows command line automatically every morning at 07:00 o'clock.

The commands is (filup person.xml).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the windows scheduler.  You will make a batch file that you save somewhere and schedule a task to execute that batch file.  Just save that command in a text file and change the extension to .bat.

Comment: That worked but opened cmd as C:\Windows\Systen32> I need open cmd as C:\Users\Alex>

Comment: Just add a cd line to the beginning of your bat file. `cd C:\Users\Alex`

Comment: Great, glad i could help.  Please mark this as the answer.

Comment: I tried many time, but gives an error that tell me I have less than 15 Reputation. :(

Comment: @alex You need 15 to vote up. You don't need any rep to accept the answer. You just need to click the grey tick which is just below the voting arrows, and it will turn green.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you, y'r right I clicked on vote up in stead click on grey Nike symbols.